# What does the command (type of [var]) do?

Tags: java

I know this is probably a simple and easy question but what does it mean and what does this command do when it shows up? :

```
int var1 = 1;
int var2 = 2;
var1 = (type of var1) (var1 + var2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't compile, but what you are referencing is the following code:

```
int var1 = 1;
int var2 = 2;
var1 += var2;
```

The `type of var1` is known as [type conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion). This changing means the data type of an entity to another.

So what you would have would be the same as:

```
int var1 = 1;
int var2 = 2;
var1 = (int)(var1 + var2);
```

But this can be used to make the following work:

```
char var1 = 'a';
double var2 = 3.14;
var1 += var2;
```

Which is the same as saying:

```
char var1 = 'a';
double var2 = 3.14;
var1 = (char)(var1 + var2);
```

Answer (score 0):

int var1 =1;
double var2 = 2.1;
var1 = int(var1 + var2); %cast ..you force the function to return the variable with type you want

Answer (score 0):

`(some_type)`, when placed in front of an expression, is a "cast" which converts the value of the expression to the named type.

There are two forms, one where `some_type` is a primitive (`int`, `char`, `double`, etc), and another where `some_type` is an object class name (`String`, `HashMap`, `MyClass`, etc).

The first type is pretty much always allowed (though it usually doesn't make sense, say, to cast from `char` to `double`, etc), but the second is much more complicated and, though the compiler will accept it, may well result in a runtime `ClassCastException`.

And you can never (except for some odd cases having to do with the "boxing" of primitive values into corresponding objects (such as `int` to `Integer`)) "cast" a primitive to a on object class or vice-versa.

Where you'll most often see casts used is converting a floating-point value to an integer one, eg:

```
double x = 345.67;
int y = (int) x;  // The result is y = 345.  Note that "rounding" does not occur.
```

or when "narrowing" an integer type such as:

```
long a = 1234567;
int b = (int) a;  // The result is b = 1234567,
                  // because all the bits of the number will fit in a 32-bit int
```

If the "cast to" type is too narrow to hold the "significant bits" of the value being cast then "truncation" of the value occurs.  Eg:

```
int c = 257;
byte d = (byte) c;  // The result is d = 1, since 257 is 0x101,
                    // and a byte only holds 8 bits or 0x01
```